# What does "straight off the Wall Street assembly line" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "another guy from Wall Street going to enter the Fed"?

Democrats including Ohio Senator Sherrod Brown have said they intend to scrutinize Quarles' ties to Wall Street during his confirmation hearing. Senator Elizabeth Warren described him as **"straight off the Wall Street assembly line"** in announcing her opposition in a statement.

Source: http://www.Reuters.com/article/us-usa-banks-regulation-quarles-idUSKBN19X2ZT?il=0

Answer (score 2):

An [assembly line](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assembly-line) is a way of making large numbers of identical products. The phrase **straight off the Wall Street assembly line** suggests that Wall Street people all share the same attitudes, and further suggests that this might not be a good thing.

Comment: I would take it a step farther; the reference is even more literal.  People in high-level finance and economy positions in the government tend to be excessively represented by ex-Wall Street people.  The quote is suggesting that Wall Street is producing people for these government positions like it's a factory.